# Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack

In my webpack:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [">0.1%", "last 4 versions", "not ie <= 9"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

But I have an error in IE:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startsWith` is a method of String, `'hello there'.startsWith('hello') === true`. It's not supported in any version of IE, but you can [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io) is great at catching a lot of this stuff with zero effort.